# Write a function that returns a subset of a string between one index and another

Tags: javascript, function, substring

function(str,indexStart,indexEnd)

Example:

((‘abcd’,1,3) return ‘bcd’)

Similar to built in function substr. I’m trying to create the function without using any built in methods (ie splice, indexOf)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), especially when it comes to [**homework questions**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Is it like you want to just give the starting index and then return the rest?

For example, in the above code, you have mentioned 10 as the end, but there are less than 10 characters. so it returns the rest?

Comment: So where do you get stuck with this? Which part do you need help with?

Comment: [Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) should do the job?

Answer (score 3):

is there any reason you can't use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)?

```
function getSubstring(str,indexStart,indexEnd) {
  return str.slice(indexStart,indexEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like slice but you may need to bounds check the indexes if you don't want to wrap around the string as slice does by default.

For example...

```
function(str,indexStart,indexEnd) {
  return str.slice(Math.max(0, indexStart), Math.min(str.length - 1, indexEnd));
}
```

Comment: In your answer, it should be `Math.max(0, indexStart)` as you are checking a lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following methods to slice the strings.

**slice**:

```
var str = "Hello world!"; 
var res = str.slice(2, 5);
```

**substring**

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(2, 5);
```

**substr**

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substr(2, 5);
```

And, `str.length` returns the length of the string you pass.

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear.
If a problem is solved using a function it can be this way

```js
function myFunction(str,indexStart,indexEnd){  
    return   str.substr(indexStart, indexEnd);  
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
        myFunction("abcd",1,10)
```

```html
<h1 id="demo" class="newClass"></h1>
```

Or do you want to use it permanently?